# Is there a full list of the allowed url parameters for github pull requests?

Tags: github, pull-request

Is there a full list of the allowed url parameters for github pull requests?
I know `"w=1"` can be used to ignore white space changes in file diffs, and something like `"ts=4"` can be used to reset tab stop width.

Comment: Have you checked the [documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/) yourself?

Comment: I don't think there is any documentation for this, we have looked for it a few times with my colleagues. We only know these two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look at this link for cool features of Git and GitHub: 
https://github.com/tiimgreen/github-cheat-sheet

They show the two parameters that you presented but sadly no others.

Answer (score 0):

Creating pull requests with query parameters are now documented!

https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/using-query-parameters-to-create-a-pull-request